# Call another Javascript function when it returns true

Tags: javascript, asp.net, imagebutton

I have an imagebutton on my page. When I click on it I am bringing confirmbox up:

```
function confirmDelete() {
   if (confirm('Do you really want to delete this Image?') == true) {
       return true;
   }
   else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

When the user clicks "Ok" on confirmbox, it deletes record from database and does a post back. The thing that I want to do is call the following function after clicking "Ok" button on confirmbox:

```
function imageViewerTool() {
   $("#overlay").show();
   $("#imageViewerDialog").fadeIn(300);
}
```

My Image Button:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgParts" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirmDelete();" />
```

Code Behind:

```
db.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.Text, "delete from tblTest where ImageName='img_1111'");
```

Comment: Protip: `function confirmDelete() { return confirm('Do you really want enter code here o delete this Image?') }`

Answer (score 2):

umm... then y don't you call it?
I mean can't you just do this:

```
function confirmDelete() {
   if (confirm('Do you really want enter code here`o delete this Image?')) {
       imageViewerTool(); // THIS
       return true;
   }
   else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Prolly, there is some scoping issue. and you are not able to reference imageViewerTool from within confirmDelete method

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my code and it now works.

JavaScript:

```
function confirmDelete() {
if (confirm('Do you really want to delete this Image?') == true)
    return true;
else
    return false;}

$(document).ready(function () {
var checkConfirm = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnCheckConfirmBox").value;
if (checkConfirm != null && checkConfirm == "yes") {
    imageViewerTool();
}});

function imageViewerTool() {
$("#overlay").show();
$("#imageViewerDialog").fadeIn(300);}

function HideImageViewerDialog() {
$('input:hidden[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnCheckConfirmBox"]').val('no');
$("#overlay").hide();
$("#imageViewerDialog").fadeOut(300);}
```

Client Side:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkClose" runat="server" OnClientClick="HideImageViewerDialog();">Close</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:ImageButton ID="imgParts" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirmDelete();" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCheckConfirmBox" runat="server" Value="no"/>
```

Server Side:

```
db.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.Text, "delete from tblTest where ImageName='img_1111'");
hdnCheckConfirmBox.Value = "yes";
```